# c++ linux accept() blocking after socket closed

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, blocking

I have a thread that listens for new connections

```
new_fd = accept(Listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *) & their_addr, &sin_size);
```

and another thread that closes Listen_fd when when it's time to close the program.  After Listen_fd is closed however, it still blocks. When I use GDB to try and debug accept() doesn't block. I thought that it could be a problem with SO_LINGER, but it shouldn't be on by default, and shouldn't change when using GDB. Any idea whats going on, or any other suggestion to closing the listing socket?

Answer (score 7):

Use: `sock.shutdown (socket.SHUT_RD)`

Then `accept` will return `EINVAL`.  No ugly cross thread signals required!

From the Python documentation:
"Note `close()` releases the resource associated with a connection but does not necessarily close the connection immediately. If you want to close the connection in a timely fashion, call `shutdown()` before `close()`."

http://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.close

I ran into this problem years ago, while programming in C.  But I only found the solution today, after running into the same problem in Python, AND pondering using signals (yuck!), AND THEN remembering the note about `shutdown`!

As for the comments that say you should not close/use sockets across threads... in CPython the global interpreter lock should protect you (assuming you are using file objects rather than raw, integer file descriptors).

Here is example code:

```
import socket, threading, time

sock = socket.socket (socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt (socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind (('', 8000))
sock.listen (5)

def child ():
  print ('child  accept ...')
  try:  sock.accept ()
  except OSError as exc :  print ('child  exception  %s' % exc)
  print ('child  exit')

threading.Thread ( target = child ).start ()

time.sleep (1)
print ('main   shutdown')
sock.shutdown (socket.SHUT_RD)

time.sleep (1)
print ('main   close')
sock.close ()

time.sleep (1)
print ('main   exit')
```

Comment: I have a C++ program that opens a listen socket in the main thread and spawns a child thread to accept incoming connections. The main thread needs to shut down the acceptor thread upon receiving a signal. `close(s)` doesn't work because `accept(…)` continues to block on the closed socket, but `shutdown(s, SHUT_RD)` makes the `accept(…)` call bail immediately with `EINVAL`. Perfect solution, and it works even if the acceptor thread is between calls to `accept(…)` when the shutdown occurs. Thanks!

Comment: For c++ code example see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62356967/70405

Comment: I've seen several answers for closing a socket from another thread. This one is super clean and doesn't use polling though! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 6):

The behavior of `accept` when called on something which is not a valid socket FD is undefined. "Not a valid socket FD" includes numbers which were once valid sockets but have since been closed. You might say "but Borealid, it's supposed to return EINVAL!", but that's not guaranteed - for instance, the same FD number might be reassigned to a different socket between your `close` and `accept` calls.

So, even if you were to isolate and correct whatever makes your program fail, you could still begin to fail again in the future. Don't do it - correct the error that causes you to attempt to `accept` a connection on a closed socket.

If you meant that a call which was *previously* made to `accept` **continues** blocking after `close`, then what you should do is send a signal to the thread which is blocked in `accept`. This will give it EINTR and it can cleanly disengage - and **then** close the socket. Don't close it from a thread other than the one using it.

Comment: +1 My guess is the last scenario.  Thread 1 is blocking on accept.  Thread 2 closes socket.  Thread1 blocks forever.

Comment: This is correct.  Note that you will probably want to install an empty signal handler for the signal that you use.

Comment: Oh this part of POSIX really sucks.

Answer (score 4):

The `shutdown()` function may be what you are looking for.  Calling `shutdown(Listen_fd, SHUT_RDWR)` will cause any blocked call to `accept()` to return `EINVAL`.  Coupling a call to `shutdown()` with the use of an atomic flag can help to determine the reason for the `EINVAL`.

For example, if you have this flag:

```
std::atomic<bool> safe_shutdown(false);
```

Then you can instruct the other thread to stop listening via:

```
shutdown_handler([&]() {
  safe_shutdown = true;
  shutdown(Listen_fd, SHUT_RDWR);
});
```

For completeness, here's how your thread could call accept:

```
while (true) {
  sockaddr_in clientAddr = {0};
  socklen_t clientAddrSize = sizeof(clientAddr);
  int connSd = accept(Listen_fd, (sockaddr *)&clientAddr, &clientAddrSize);
  if (connSd < 0) {
    // If shutdown_handler() was called, then exit gracefully
    if (errno == EINVAL && safe_shutdown)
      break;
    // Otherwise, it's an unrecoverable error
    std::terminate();
  }
  char clientname[1024];
  std::cout << "Connected to "
            << inet_ntop(AF_INET, &clientAddr.sin_addr, clientname,
                         sizeof(clientname))
            << std::endl;
  service_connection(connSd);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a workaround, but you could `select` on `Listen_fd` with a timeout, and if a timeout occured check that you're about to close the program. If so, exit the loop, if not, go back to step 1 and do the next `select`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking the return value of close?
From linux manpages, (http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/close.2.html)
"It is probably unwise to close file descriptors while they may be in use by system calls in other threads in the same process.  Since a file descriptor may be reused, there are some obscure race conditions that may cause unintended side effects".
You can use a select instead of an accept and wait for some event from the other thead, then close the socket in the listener thread.