# Boost ASIO: do we need to keep using async_read and write inside a function called from async_read?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have been trying to understand the logic in boost's [http server 3 example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html). The request in this example is read inside connection.cpp, in the start() method, which calls:

```
socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer_),
      strand_.wrap(
        boost::bind(&connection::handle_read, shared_from_this(),
          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
          boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)));
```

Note that the async_read_some method is [documented to return immediately](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_read_some.html). Then inside the read handler (`connection::handle_read()`), we may again call async_read_some if parse returns `boost::indeterminate`. What benefit does this provide over `socket_.read_some(buffer)`, given that we already know we are working in a separate thread. The reason I ask is I want to change the message parsing a bit to call read_some on demand, but the method I have in mind won't work with an async read.

Also, a related question: is there any difference between

`async_read_some()`

and

`boost::thread th([](){ ret = read_some(); handle_read(ret) });`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boost.Asio's [HTTP Server 3](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html#boost_asio.examples.http_server_3)'s example is coded in a way that it remains agnostic to the size of the thread pool.  As such, there is no guarantee that work will be done in separate threads.  Nevertheless, the benefit in being agnostic is that it scales better with more connections.  For example, consider the [C10K problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html) that examines 10000 clients simultaneously connected.  A synchronous solution may run into various performance issues or resource limitations with 10000 clients.  Additionally, the asynchronous nature helps insulate the program from behavior changes in the network.  For instance, consider a synchronous program that has 3 clients and 2 threads, but 2 of the clients have high latency due to an increase in noise on the network.  The 3rd client could be inadvertently affected if both of the threads are blocked waiting for data from the other clients.

If there is a low and finite number of connections, with each connection serviced by a thread, then the performance difference between a synchronous and asynchronous server may be minimal.  When possible, it is often advised to avoid mixing asynchronous and synchronous programming, as it can turn a complex solution into a complicated one.  Furthermore, most synchronous algorithms can be written asynchronously.

There are two major differences between an asynchronous operation and a synchronous operation (even those running within a dedicated thread):

- Thread safety.  As noted in the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html):

  > In general, it is safe to make concurrent use of distinct objects, but unsafe to make concurrent use of a single object.

  Therefore, asynchronous and synchronous operations cannot safely be initiated while a synchronous operation is in progress, even if the operation is invoked within its own thread.  This may be minimal in a half duplex protocol, but should be considered with full duplex protocols.
- Ability to cancel an operation.  As noted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11195223/1053968) answer, synchronous operations cannot be cancelled through the `cancel()` member functions Boost.Asio provides.  Instead, the application may need to use lower level mechanics, such as signals.

Comment: Thanks for the description - I've not done a lot of socket programming so this was enlightening. My only gripe with the HTTP Server 3 code is that consume is overly verbose; server 4 is slightly less so, but still seems like too much. What I was trying for is to write `if (++_reader != 'H' || ++_reader != 'T' || ++_reader != 'T' || ++_reader != 'P' || ++_reader != '/')
  return false;`, with `reader::operator++` calling `read_some` if it runs out of data in its buffer. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like this is possible with async operations.