# Could not unblock the boost asio acceptor

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, tcp, boost-asio

I am trying to cancel a TCP acceptor by the programs keeps blocked in that line.

One thread waits for connections like this:

```
boost::system::error_code ec;
acceptor_ = new boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor(io_service_, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port));
acceptor_->accept(socket_, ec);  // socket_ is a boost::asio::ip::tcp:socket
```

The thread that must close the acceptor does:

```
boost::system::error_code ec;
acceptor_->close(ec);
```

Is there something I am missing? I am not using any async operation, so may I do something with the io_service object?

Comment: You could try using `acceptor_->cancel();` before closing it. I'm using that in my program and it works fine. However I think `close()` should also work. Are you sure you are working on the same acceptor object?

Comment: Yes, same acceptor of course. My code works on Windows but not on Linux, any ideas?

Comment: What is the stack trace when `close()` blocks? Why are you canceling from [another thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/acceptor.html)?

Comment: Why can not cancel the acceptor from another thread? I mean, if accept is a blocking operation, how can I cancel it from the same thread?

Answer (score 1):

In short, you cannot cancel most of async operations using **asio** function and methods.

The problem is underlying `accept`, `read` etc are system calls. They cannot be interrupted using `io_service::stop` or `cancel` since accepting thread is blocked inside syscall, not asio event loop. They only can be interrupted by killing thread or sending a signal.

I'd prefer to make this acceptor asyncronous, so problem will gone. Also see [this Q on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191028/boostasio-how-to-interrupt-a-blocked-tcp-server-thread) about this