# How to terminate a socket accept blocking

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking

I developed a server with C code.

I used the `accept()` function to keep my server listening on a giving socket.

My server is launched in a thread.

Now in other thread and for some condition I want to stop the `accept()` blocking and then close the related socket.

How I can do that? Could `shutdown()` do that?

Comment: I'm not positive but I suspect you could simply `close()` the socket that `accept()` is on. Perhaps `shutdown()` does that. What happened when you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Boost::asio - how to interrupt a blocked tcp server thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191028/boostasio-how-to-interrupt-a-blocked-tcp-server-thread)

Answer (score 4):

[This does not work on Windows]

- Use [`sigaction()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) to install a signal handler for let's say `SIGUSR1` doing nothing, but having the `SA_RESTART` option unset (also see section "*Interruption of system calls and library functions by signal handlers*" on this [man-page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)).
- Then send the blocking process a `SIGUSR1` signal.

`accept()` will then return `-1` and set `errno` to `EINTR`.

Answer (score 3):

Classically, closing the socket from another thread causes the accept() call to return with an error.  I have been told that this does not work on some releases of Linux, but have seen no evidence of that myself - every time, on Windows/Linux, the accept() returns with an error/exception.

The other common solution is to check some 'shutdown' atomic boolean after every accept() return.  When you want to stop it, set the boolean and perform a connect() on the localhost stack, so causing the accept() to return in the 'normal' way.

Comment: Should be slightly corrected: instead of close() do shutdown() for portable solution. More details here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62356967/70405 . Don't mind the boost involvement, solution is at socket API level.

Answer (score 2):

I was having trouble with `accept` not terminating after I only called `close` on the socket under Linux Mint 18.3. I solved it by also calling `shutdown(socket_fd, SHUT_RD);` before the `close`

mah already mentioned it, but I wanted to highlight this, because this is the first SO result in a google search for "socket stop accept".