# Communicate with a WallpaperService

Tags: android, ipc, live-wallpaper

**Is there any way to directly communicate with a `WallpaperService` from an `Activity`?** It doesn't look like I can use the normal service communication classes because the `onBind` method is declared `final` in the WallpaperService class I'm extending. Worth noting that I'm referring to *my* WallpaperService not *any*.

Any workarounds if this isn't possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution was to use local sockets. I created an instance of a `LocalServerSocket` in the constructor of my wallpaper's `Engine`. Here's a quick implementation. Server runs on a separate thread and is directly tied to the lifecycle of `MyEngine`. The thread will stop when `continueSocket` is set to `false`. This happens `onDestroy`. [Problem is that `LocalServerSocket.accept()` blocks until there's something to do.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29939) The workaround is to send a message to our own server so it will run through the loop again and check `continueSocket` (which is now `false`), closing the server. Check the `closeSocketServer` method. I have it running in `onDestroy` in the example but you might want to use it elsewhere like `onSurfaceDestroyed` and add your own sanity checks.

```
public class MyWallpaperService extends WallpaperService {
    @Override
    public Engine onCreateEngine() {
        return new MyEngine();
    }

    private class MyEngine extends Engine {

        private boolean continueSocket = true;

        MyEngine() {
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        LocalServerSocket server = new LocalServerSocket("MyAddress");
                        Log.d("SERVER READY", "Server is ready.");
                        while(continueSocket) {
                            LocalSocket receiver = server.accept();
                            if(receiver != null) {
                                InputStream input = receiver.getInputStream();
                                byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(input);
                                Log.d("GOT DATA", new String(data));
                            }
                        }
                        server.close();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Log.wtf("IOEXCEPTION", ex);
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            closeSocketServer();
            super.onDestroy();
        }

        private void closeSocketServer() {
            continueSocket = false;
            try {
                LocalSocket socket = new LocalSocket();
                socket.connect(new LocalSocketAddress("MyAddress"));
                socket.getOutputStream().write(new byte[0]);
                socket.getOutputStream().close();
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                //
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in my `Activity` it can be as simple as this...

```
try {
    LocalSocket sender = new LocalSocket();
    sender.connect(new LocalSocketAddress("MyAddress"));
    String data = "Hello world!";
    Log.d("SENT DATA", data);
    sender.getOutputStream().write(data.getBytes());
    sender.getOutputStream().close();
    sender.close();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Log.wtf("IOEXCEPTION", ex);
}
```

Logcat ends up looking like this:

```
D/SERVER READY﹕ Server is ready. (when the wallpaper starts up)
D/SENT DATA﹕ Hello world! (when the activity sends data)
D/GOT DATA﹕ Hello world! (when the wallpaper gets the data)
```

Comment: It seems, that ordinary Linux sockets [also do not return from `accept` after being closed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19239058/1643723). Apparently, this can be fixed by calling `shutdown` on the socket (at least on versions after Lollipop):

    `android.system.Os.shutdown(socalServerSocket.getFileDescriptor(), 0);`

Answer (score 1):

In your WallpaperService onCreateEngine:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("your.package.your.action");
MyBroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver(mRenderer);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
        .registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
```

In mRenderer's class:

```
public void receiveCommand(int i) {
    Log.d("got", String.valueOf(i));
}
```

Receiver class:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private final MyRenderer _mRenderer;

    public MyBroadcastReceiver(MyRenderer mRenderer) {
        _mRenderer = mRenderer;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        _mRenderer.receiveCommand(intent.getExtra("msg", -1));
    }
}
```

Now call from activity:

```
Intent in = new Intent();
in.setAction("your.package.your.action");
in.setExtra("msg", 42);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(in);
```